# Using StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase

Tags: c#

I have the following code lines:

```
var c = value.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Culture == Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);

var d = value.FirstOrDefault(x => String.Equals(x.Culture == Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Basically I am looking for an item which culture (string) is the same as the current thread culture.

If the current culture is `"en-US"` I would like to get the item even if its culture is `"en-us"` ... So I want to ignore case.

What is strange is that `"c"` becomes the item but `"d"` is null ...

Any idea why?

Comment: In you code example, there is no = operator between `d` and `value`. Is that a typo only in the example or in your actual code, too?

Comment: The `==` inside the `String.Equals` might be the issue. Did you read your code and step through it with the debugger first?

Comment: @EvanMulawski - I'd say it *is* the issue. It's turned this into a call to `String.Equals(string,string)` where a boolean and an enum value are being implicitly converted to strings.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't it be?

```
var d = value.FirstOrDefault(x => String.Equals(x.Culture, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here:

```
var d ... x.Culture == Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name
```

This evaluates to `true`, so `string.Equals` where it is used yields unexpected results.

So the right code:

```
var d = value.FirstOrDefault(x => String.Equals(x.Culture, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```